# What program can bake transparent light maps?

Tags: lighting

So I have this racing game I'm trying to modify that uses lightmaps that fade to transparency for light sources. An example from the game:

[image]

I've been trying to produce a similar effect but with no luck. I've tried blender but that doesn't support transparency off of light sources, if anyone has any program ideas I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what sort of lightmaps are produced by blender. Perhaps if you can get it to render a non-transparent lightmap (for example one that has all the colours you want but on a black background), you could then use a program to remove all of the black. I believe GIMP and Photoshop both have a colour to alpha tool. Be sure to pick a background colour that will not be the same colour as any of the lights.